# PHP Superglobals in another file

Tags: php, superglobals

I want to declare a variable (php code) in file file_one and use it in file_two.

According to its documentation, superblogals can be accessed from everywhere. But not in my case maybe??
I declared $a in the first file but I am not able to use it in the second file.
Although I can use it in a function inside the first file.

```
$GLOBALS['a']= 3;

function test() {
  echo $GLOBALS['a'];
} 

test();
```

This works as expected. But:

file_one:

```
    $GLOBALS['a']= 3;
```

file_two:

```
    echo $GLOBALS['a'];
```

causes a Notice: Undefined index: a

Include 'file_one.php" is not something I want to use, bebause file_one makes a lot more things.

Comment: _"Include 'file_one.php" is not something I want to use"_ - Then how would the code in `file_one.php` get loaded and executed? You need to include it somewhere. Are you asking about keeping the data between requests or in different files during the same request?`

Comment: What you are looking for are [session variables](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.session.php)

Comment: Create file_three and use it only for globals, then include it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store the value of global in a session variable. It will work. Or you can define it in your head/header/function or in any common file.

Comment: It worked, yes! But why $GLOBALS didn't do the job?

Comment: Because the global variable can only be accessed within the file.